# How to increase bittorrent download speed?

Tags: dart, bittorrent

I am developing a bittorrent client with Dart.

Now this client support: TCP regular bittorrent protocal, DHT protocal, Peer Exchange, UDP/HTTP/HTTPS tracker.When the client try to download something, it can find more than 1000 peer addresses, but just can connect only around 30 peers, and some of them response very slowly.

For example, If I use other bt client (Bitcomet) to download something, the downloading speed is over 1MB/S, but for the same resource, my client's downloading speed is just around 100kb/s

I want to know how to increase my client downloading speed? Try to find more peers? Implements more bittorrent specifications?

Comment: I assume you are using a library to implement your bittorrent client. No?

Comment: no, I implemented bt specifications by Dart language, such as bencode,bep0003 and others ，but not all. I want to know how can increase the downloading speed so I can know which bt specification I should implemented first priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't see your client in action, so we don't know why it is slow. Besides supported bittorrent features and correct implementation of the specification there also are things such as inefficiently implemented socket programming that could slow you down.
So you will have to investigate and compare your client with another from many angles.

To start with you'll want to use a client with very fine-grained logging as reference so you can understand their behavior. [libtorrent](https://libtorrent.org/) and some clients based on it provide that, so does [biglybt](https://www.biglybt.com/).

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is also a useful tool to look at bittorrent and TCP at the network level. To snapshot the current buffering state of sockets you can use [`ss -tie`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html).

> When the client try to download something, it can find more than 1000 peer addresses, but just can connect only around 30 peers, and some of them response very slowly.

Well, that's where I'd would start to compare. Are you processing the peer sources (DHT, tracker) correctly, i.e. are you getting the IP addresses correctly?

Do peers immediately disconnect the client - which would indicate a bug or missing piece in your protocol implementation - or other network errors during connection setup?

Do you get any incoming (remote-initiated) connections? If not you'll have to forward your TCP listening port or implement UPnP-IGD or PCP in that case. Or [uTP](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html) + [hole punching](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0055.html).

> Implements more bittorrent specifications?

Since you already implemented PEX you also must have [BEP 10](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0010.html) implemented, make sure to honor the `reqq` field in that case. Implementing the [fast extension (BEP6)](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0006.html) can also be useful to avoid some complications in the accounting of pending requests.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I have try the first one : check DHT, tracker and ip address parse, I found some issues with tracker (no timeout retry , some response parse incorrect) , ip parse(no ipv6) etc and fix them, I add a future to get  more public trackers url , these improves help my client get more peers address(more active peers,more seeder) now , for the same resource , the downloading speed increase to  600kb/s from 300kb/s. Actually my client can listening incoming peer (TCP listening , but I got few incoming connections , usually it's none ).

Comment: Even I can find more peer address , but many of them can not connect , maybe they are listening with uTP not TCP? anyway I am developing uTP now ,any improve I will comment here. Thanks for your reply again!

Comment: If you're not getting incoming connections that would indicate that either your tracker announces are wrong (incorrect port? missing state query?) or that you're not performing port forwarding through your NAT.

Comment: Hi again. UTP stucks me over 2 weeks :( 

When I developing the UTP , its specification give a method which can control the window size , I thought that this method can be use to control 'piece request' buffer size of the bt peer , so I change my stupid ‘one-by-one request policy’ (request buffer max size is only 5 ， dont allow change , when it's full , wait for a "piece response"  to remove the old request to allow new piece request) . I use the same method to control the max income requests number( for one peer)

Comment: Because my max request buffer size was only 5 before , so when some peer send me the over 5 requests one time , I will close the socket. Back to your 3rd suggestion , now I understand what `reqq` is. 
 
Now for some seeder , the download speed can grow up to about 1mb/s , I am very exsiting!

Do you have any other suggestion about UTP?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to implement utp yourself (rather than using existing libraries such as libutp) then you need to understand network congestion control algorithms in general (as used in TCP) and then specifically LEDBAT as it's supposed to be used with utp. And once you have utp implemented you'll want to use it for NAT hole punching via the ut_holepunch extension

Comment: Have done utp and holepunch(with pex). In my honest , it can not make big progress for downloading. Some utp seeder can be connected via TCP directly(outgoing connection, peer is reachable) , in the fact , most of the utp peer are leecher and dont have resource also.

Comment: Well, if you have followup questions you probably should open a new one. Right now there's not enough data to tell what's missing. As suggested in my answer the best option is to compare with another, fast client and see what it's doing differently.